# How to merge two wildcard expressions

Tags: loops, merge, sh

In a shell script, I need to apply the same shell code to all files that either have `.F90` or `.F` as extension.

For the moment I use

```
for file in *.F90 ;do ...
    # Code I need to run

for file in *.F; do ...
    # Same block of code copy-pasted.
```

Is there a way to merge these two loops making an array of matching files then applying the action ?

Comment: Edited: The title and wording of the question was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, because I don't see why you would need an array.

This would be legal syntax:

```
for file in *.F90 *.F ; do ...
```

To keep a list of the files impacted, you could do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files="*.F90 *.F"
for file in ${files} ; do ...
```

*Note: the `nullglob` line prevents lame (IMO) behavior should *.F90 or *.F not match any files.*

Comment: ha ok thanks ! an array or a list . A way to have a record of files impacted

Comment: @froggy see my undated example

Comment: `for file in *.F90 *.F` is fine, but don't try to store the glob in a (non-array) parameter. The unquoted expansion will not correctly handle matching file names that contain whitespace.